# Extern variable in ISR

Tags: interrupt

Is it safe to use extern data qualifier for a variable in an ISR?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming C: yes, but you need to mark the variable wth keyword volatile to let the compiler know its value can change in more than one thread (the interrupt is basically a different thread).

Comment: Keep in mind you might some kind of locking/atomic operations when accessing such a variable if it's on a multi processor machine, or the variable are accessed in multiple ISRs

Comment: @nos: Could you please elaborate your comment?

Comment: @nos is talking about thread safety. Think about this, if your main and your ISR share a variable x. If your main is changing this variable and it can't change it atomically, if ISR happens while your main is half way changing the variable, when ISR returns, your main will have garbled values.  For embedded systems with ISR, check out keywords like reentrancy and thread safety (there is no thread here but ISR is kind of like one).